# Pop3 in metasploitable

Tags: linux, telnet, pop3

I am trying to check the POP3 service in metasploitable machine. the following command in the metasploitable machine

```
~$ telnet localhost 110
```

says, connection refused.
there is no firewall in the system. Please suggest the solution to it.

Comment: Are you sure it is running on port 110?

Comment: no, but this is the default port for pop3 as far the best of knowledge.

Comment: Yeah well obviously it is not the one. What is the operating system? Also, POP3 with with SSL is usually run on 995.

Comment: As I have mentioned, it's "metasplotable", the vulnerable version of the "ubuntu server". and I am trying pop3 with telnet. I haven't try SSL though.

Comment: I hope you are doing this for learning purposes, and are not actually trying to make us help you with a hacked machine.

Comment: That said, you can use `netstat -anp | grep LISTEN` to see all open ports and their assigned processes.

Comment: Ofcourse, it's the basic learning. there is no way I take help to hack into someone's machine, against the law. I just don't know, what am I missing.

Comment: You are not missing anything, POP3 probably does not exist on the machine?

Comment: it doesn't return anything. By the way, why do we use LISTEN for grep?

Comment: that was my initial guess, any way to put that there?

Comment: `netstat -apn` returns all open ports, both connected, and listening. When you pipe it to `grep LISTEN` it returns only the listening ports.

Comment: ok, so how can I get the needed package and start the server? By the way, I cannot grant it access to the internet since it is totally vulnerable